# Why do I have "errors=remount-ro" option in my ext4 partition in my Linux?

Tags: linux, mount, ext4, fstab

In mount man page `errors=remount-ro` is an option for mounting fat but this option doesn't appear in ext4 options catalog.
I know what this option means: In case of mistake remounting the partition like readonly but I don't know if it's a correct option or only a bug.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is perfectly valid for ext4, and is defined in the [`ext4` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html):

> `errors={continue|remount-ro|panic}`
>
> Define the behavior when an error is encountered.  (Either
>                 ignore errors and just mark the filesystem erroneous and
>                 continue, or remount the filesystem read-only, or panic and
>                 halt the system.)  The default is set in the filesystem
>                 superblock, and can be changed using [`tune2fs(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tune2fs.8.html).

[Some versions](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/mount/mount.8) of the `mount` manpage do list this option for ext4; [others](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) refer to the manpage linked above:

> **Mount options for ext2, ext3 and ext4**
>
> See the options section of the [`ext2(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext2.5.html), [`ext3(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext3.5.html) or [`ext4(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html) man page
>          (the `e2fsprogs` package must be installed).